# I want split String including "," or " ’ " but i do not want "," or " ’ " to appear in my output?

Tags: java

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String A=sc.nextLine();

```
 String array[] = A.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(array.length);
 for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
     System.out.println(array[i]);
 }
```

Comment: `I really, really can't understand what you want` <== If this was your text, what do you expect to get? These words: `I`, `really`, `really`, `can`, `t`, `understand`, `what`, `you`, `want`?

Comment: i put textfield on JFrame,I wrote actionperformed method in java , and i want any event done when i write in textfield and click(Enter)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
text.split("[,']+"); // split by , or '
```

If you also to include `\s`, you can do:

```
text.split("[\\s,']+");
```